# Shopping Cart with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, e-commerce, payment, checkout, shopping-cart

Does anyone know where I can get some high quality step by step info on creating a full shopping cart for an asp.net mvc 5 ecommerce application? I have seen examples out there but none of them talk about how to add working payment methods and creating a secure checkout. I want to build something like shopify checkout that is secure and simple. I just keep finding examples on everything BEFORE you reach checkout, like sessions and user adding to cart and seeing the view cart etc...

I have read the book **Professional ASP.NET MVC 5 by Jon Galloway** where he has the example of the MVC Music store, but nothing about how to actually process payments and all that. I know checkout has to also meet a bunch of requirements required by the processor and the gateway (don't wanna get hacked and sued or anything).. How do I even start / approach a project like this?

Can someone help push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind That iam still Newbie :)

Most of the Payment Gateway Providers are similar, in term of Payment Integration. But some might request extra/other information.

Example of Asp.net 5 + Stripe GateWay:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMWWeAkAviA&ab_channel=KaushikRoyChowdhury

I came across a question on Stackoverflow regarding payments, it's suggetst that as an "website owner" not to keep/store credit card information, instead let the Gateway Payment handle the information.

Link to the topic:
[Storing Credit Card Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282028/storing-credit-card-information)