# How get the card type from reading a range of bins

Tags: java

I am trying to get a range of card type from a list bins that are associated with that card type, but whenever I ran the code the card-type is printed as null am not sure what I am doing wrong

This are the bins in a text

```
400000000000,499999999999,visa
500000000000,599999999999,mc
400000000000,499999999999,visa
420008000000,420008999999,visadebit
420008000000,435000999999,visa
540008000000,599999999999,mc
```

Whenever I Pass 4111111111111111 instead of getting visa i end getting null,

this is what I have done so far

```
package cardsystem;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    /**
     * An entity to hold bin range details. A bin range is a pair of 12 digit numbers that
     * mark the boundaries of the range which is maped to other bin range properties such
     * as a card type. The range boundaries are inclusive.
     */
    static final class BinRange {
        final String start;
        final String end;
        final String cardType;

        BinRange(String start, String end, String cardType) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.cardType = cardType;
        }
    }


    //  I need a hashmap which hold index and CardType. Each index corresponding an interval (start-end).
    private static HashMap<Integer, String> cache = new HashMap<>();
    private static List<Long> startEndList = new ArrayList<>();

    interface CardTypeCache {
        /**
         * @param cardNumber 12 to 23 digit card number.
         * @return the card type for this cardNumber or null if the card number does not
         * fall into any valid bin ranges.
         */
        String get(String cardNumber);
    }

    /**
     * @param binRanges the list of card bin ranges to build a cache from.
     * @return an implementation of CardTypeCache.
     */
    public static CardTypeCache buildCache(List<BinRange> binRanges) {

        cache = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < binRanges.size(); i++) {
            cache.put(i, binRanges.get(i).cardType);
        }

        for (BinRange binRange : binRanges) {
            startEndList.add(Long.valueOf(binRange.start)); // Previously, Integer type used, I converted it to 'Long' type
            startEndList.add(Long.valueOf(binRange.end));
        }

        return new CardTypeCacheImpl();
    }

    static class CardTypeCacheImpl implements CardTypeCache {


        public String get(String cardNumber) {

            //Integer index = findIndexLinear(Long.valueOf(cardNumber));    // Linear Search
            Integer index = findIndexBinary(Long.valueOf(cardNumber));      // Binary Search
            return (index != -1) ? cache.get(index) : "null";
        }

        /**
         * Linear Search O(n)
         *
         * @param cardNumber, Searching an index which is between start-end .
         * @return an index. If not found, return -1.
         */
        private Integer findIndexLinear(Long cardNumber) {

            for (int i = 1; i < startEndList.size(); i += 2) {
                if (startEndList.get(i - 1) <= cardNumber && cardNumber <= startEndList.get(i)) {
                    return i / 2;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        /**
         * Binary Search O(logn)
         *
         * @param cardNumber, Searching an index which is between start-end .
         * @return an index. If not found, return -1.
         */
        private Integer findIndexBinary(Long cardNumber) {

            int left = 0;
            int right = startEndList.size();

            while (left < right) {

                int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

                if (mid % 2 == 0 && startEndList.get(mid) <= cardNumber && cardNumber <= startEndList.get(mid + 1)) { // right pair (start-end) of mid
                    return mid / 2;
                } else if (mid % 2 == 1 && startEndList.get(mid - 1) <= cardNumber && cardNumber <= startEndList.get(mid)) {  // left pair
                    return mid / 2;
                }

                if (cardNumber < startEndList.get(mid)) {
                    right = mid;
                } else {
                    left = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        
        File text = new File("D:/dev/CardSystem/src/cardsystem/input.txt");

        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text)) {
            List<Solution.BinRange> binRanges = new ArrayList<>();
            
            /*
            4111111111111111
            400000000000,499999999999,visa
            500000000000,599999999999,mc
            */

            String cardNumber = scanner.next();
            scanner.nextLine();

            scanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String start = scanner.next();
                String end = scanner.next();
                String cardType = scanner.next();
                binRanges.add(new Solution.BinRange(start, end, cardType));
                if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    scanner.nextLine();
                }
            }

            Solution.CardTypeCache cache = Solution.buildCache(binRanges);
            if (cache != null) {
                bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(cache.get(cardNumber)));
            }
        }

        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, been scratching my head for hours

Comment: What you are doing incorrect is that you are using the wrong type to represent the credit card numbers.  The number 4111,1111,1111,1111 is roughly 4.1 x 10^16.  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2^31 - 1 which is 2,147,483,647.  A credit card number doesn't fit in an `int`.

Comment: Hi @StephenC what is the best way?

Comment: Use `String` to represent credit card numbers.  They are not really integers at all.  They are identifiers composed of a fixed number of decimal digits.

Comment: And if this was a real application that handled real credit card numbers, it is recommended that you use a `byte[]` or `char[]` in-memory representation that can be erased after use.  See [Should credit card numbers be stored as strings or ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199559)

Comment: Hi @StephenC can you help me out on the code with a solution if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes, I do mind.  You should be able to work it out a solution for yourself.  Hint: take a look at the operations that are provided by `TreeMap`.  If you use the `ceiling` and `floor` methods for looking up the credit card numbers. you can use the map to neatly represent ranges / bins.  (Doing your homework yourself is a better way to learn to program.)

Comment: Hi @StephenC I choose to trim the number to 12 digits so as to much the bin,

Comment: There are a few ways to implement this.  But the most important thing is that you learn how to work it out for yourself.

Comment: HI @StephenCapart from triming, what other ways do you have in mind? It is good i get more than one perspective on how to tackle this.

Comment: See my previous hint!!!  If you use TreeMap to do the range search (in O(logN)) you can rip out your custom binary chop code.  And even a simple loop or (yuck) a sequence of `if ... else if` tests (both O(N)) may be reasonable solutions if the number of bins (N) is small.

Comment: @StephenC thank you so much for taking time to answer,  and what if the bin is huge, over 10million bins? what would be the best approach?

Comment: Possibly a database.  Possibly a TreeMap.  Possibly others.  But that is a different problem to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM

```
400000000000,499999999999,visa
500000000000,599999999999,mc
400000000000,499999999999,visa
420008000000,420008999999,visadebit
420008000000,435000999999,visa
540008000000,599999999999,mc
```

TO

```
400000000000,499999999999,visa
500000000000,599999999999,mc
400000000000,499999999999,visa
420008000000,420008999999,visadebit
420008000000,435000999999,visa
540008000000,599999999999,mc
```

you can try and trim the numbers to the left and omit everything that exceeds 12 digits and then you will get  a print of the card type to the console

here is a line to add

```
 cardNumber = cardNumber.length() > 13 ? cardNumber.substring(0, 12) : cardNumber;
```

so the whole function will look like

```
public String get(String cardNumber) {

        cardNumber = cardNumber.length() > 13 ? cardNumber.substring(0, 12) : cardNumber;
        Integer index = findIndexLinear(Long.valueOf(cardNumber));    // Linear Search
        //Integer index = findIndexBinary(Long.valueOf(cardNumber));      // Binary Search
        return (index != -1) ? cache.get(index) : "null";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you print the output:

```
bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(cache.get(cardNumber)));
```

The `cardNumber` is "4111111111111111", and you look for it to be in one of the ranges.

```
4111 1111 1111 1111
4000 0000 0000
```

I think your card number is outside every range specified in your file. So you can edit your file, i.e.

FROM

```
400000000000,499999999999,visa
500000000000,599999999999,mc
400000000000,499999999999,visa
420008000000,420008999999,visadebit
420008000000,435000999999,visa
540008000000,599999999999,mc
```

TO

```
4000000000000000,4999999999999999,visa
5000000000000000,5999999999999999,mc
4000000000000000,4999999999999999,visa
4200080000000000,4200089999999999,visadebit
4200080000000000,4350009999999999,visa
5400080000000000,5999999999999999,mc
```

Comment: Hi @Francesco thank you for guiding me towards the light lol